# How to use views to filter specific workflow state in current month

Tags: views, workflows

I have a system that is heavily workflow dependant. I have a content type called 'Profile' with 3 states :

1. Lead
2. Prospect
3. Customer

I would like to know how to create a views contextual filter of all Profiles that changed to the Customer state in a given month i.e. which Profiles Customer this month. 
D6 Views 2.x has this option but I cannot find it in D7 Views 3.x

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check if using the [Views Date Format SQL](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_date_format_sql) module could be a solution for you. Here are some quotes about it (from its project page):

> ... allows to format date fields using SQL.
>
> The core functionality is to remove the date formatting from render() and put it in query(). I.e. format date values using SQL's DATE_FORMAT rather than PHP's format_date.
>   This is achieved by assigning a new default handler to node 'created' and 'changed' date fields. This handler extends and overrides views's build in views_handler_field_date.
>
> The UI is completely unobtrusive, only a single checkbox "Use SQL to format dates" is added to the handler configuration popup.

Your question is not about creating charts in Drupal, but you may want to refer to [this comment](https://www.drupal.org/node/1237096#comment-7697321) also for an example of how we typically use it within the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module.